# OnHover run php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Okay I'm not really sure how to approach this. I have a user-generated post board where people post, it drops down onto a list of a bunch of posts. When you click on the ID number of the post it will bring you to a separate page with just that post and the comments on the post. I want it so when you hover over the href it drops down something that tells the user there are x amount of comments on this post. This way people know if there is comments without switching pages and also being able to be able to click the href still and go to the postid page.

I assume some ajax/jquery/javascript would be used to accomplish this but since I'm fairly new to ajax and jquery I'm not certain how this would be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For a hover effect, it would be better if that information was already stored on the page and just hidden. Then when the user does hover, you can just un-hide it and have it positioned where you want, and then hide it again when their mouse leaves the area. Using AJAX requests for this purpose would waste away a lot of HTTP requests for such a tiny amount of information.

Really, you could do the hover effect using pure CSS if you wanted too (I would).

Answer (score 2):

Since a hover happens fairly often, I wouldn't use it as the default event to fire an AJAX-request. This would increase the HTTP-traffic enormous. See if you can fetch this information when the page is build (and put it in then) or use something else like a "preview"-button for the event.

---

Anyways, this would be the basic workflow if you want/need to use AJAX:

Write a PHP-script (or any other language you use) which fetches the number of comments (and what else you want to display) from the database (or where your data is stored).

This script should then be called via AJAX (with [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) from jQuery for example). As the expected return-type you would then use `json`.

The script which fetches your data would then create an object, use PHP's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)-function to encode this object to JSON and echo it out.

This JSON-object will then be available in the success-method of the `ajax()`-method from jQuery. Then, you can access its members (e.g. the comment-count).